# Reading CSV File into Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I am attempting to open a CSV file that contains 4 columns with about 100 rows. I want to have a 2D numpy array, that sets the first column as the x-coordinates and sets the second column as the y-coordinates.

```
import numpy as np

dataDocument = open("data.csv")
headers = dataDoument.readline()

def generateArray(dataDocument):
    for numbers in dataDocument:
        splitDocument = numbers.strip().split(",")
        myArray = np.array(splitDocument[0], splitDocument[1])
        
        return myArray 
       
print(generateArray(dataDocument))
```

I keep getting various error messages, the most common being 'data type "" not understood.' Any suggestions on where my logic error/general code error exists?

Comment: You need to be specific on the errors here. You may be able to use numpy directly or at leave use the CSV module to read the file. From what I can see, though, the current approach probably shouldn't _error_ (The `return` in the `for` loop is a definite issue, though)

Comment: This is the most common error I receive: data type "" not understood

Comment: thy this line in your method: myArray = np.array((splitDocument[0], splitDocument[1]))

Comment: Seems to solve the issue, thanks very much! How do I edit my code to get it to return multiple array's (one for each row in the code)?

Comment: if you can provide a "masked" data I can look into ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt    
data = genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')

res = data[:,0:2]
```

Comment: The question suggests that it's comma-delimited, not tab-delimited

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
 import numpy as np
 d = np.loadtxt('a.csv', delimiter=',')
 x = d[:,0]
 y = d[:,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> replace: myArray = np.array(splitDocument[0], splitDocument[1])
> with: myArray = np.array((splitDocument[0], splitDocument[1])) 
> in your method and should solve the issue.
> ```

Problem is due that you are passing the `splitDocument[1]`to your `np.array` as dtype parameter.